# Talend Jobs not running

Tags: etl, talend

I'm completely new to the Talend ETL tool and have just created my first Job. However, when I tried to execute it, it gives me the following error:-

```
 Execution failed : Failed to generate code.
```

[----------
1. ERROR in E:\BizTel\TOS_BD-r111943-V5.4.1\workspace.JETEmitters\src\org\talend\designer\codegen\translators\technical\TSortOutBeginJava.java (at line 1)
    package org.talend.designer.codegen.translators.technical;
    ^

### The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

1. ERROR in E:\BizTel\TOS_BD-r111943-V5.4.1\workspace.JETEmitters\src\org\talend\designer\codegen\translators\technical\TSortOutBeginJava.java (at line 421)
   stringBuffer.append(TEXT_1);
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   ### The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

2 problems (2 errors)]

Now, I'm certain this error has nothign to do with the Job i built as the job was built following this tutorial 
    "http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=1#step14"

I tried googling a little about this on the web. I tired some approaches based on that but to no avail.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: can you first try to execute some sample jobs which comes by default with talend and see whether they run successfully, as if they also do not run then it could be that your installation is incorrect or some other issue.

Comment: Another good test is to try switching to the "Code" tab in TOS: when your Job is open, at the bottom of the designer screen, on top of Properties, there are two tabs: Designer and Code. Swith to Code tab and TOS will generate Java code for you. If it will not - then something goes wrong and probably there will be some error on the screen which you have to solve first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall TOS.
Possibly the code generation engine has not been properly loaded and occasionally, files are corrupted in Talend.

Also, You can try to restore the items to see if it is OK with you.

1. Back up the workspace.
2. Delete the workspace and restart the studio
3. Import all items from the backup of workspace done in step1.